# The sequelize.sync() will work only when model define is in the same file

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a node.js (typescript) app with connecting to database Postgres, but found the sequlize.sync() method doesn't work well.
This is my database.ts file:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import path from "path";
import { env } from "process";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import Order from "../models/order";

if(env.NODE_ENV === "production"){    
    dotenv.config({path: path.resolve("./dist", ".env")});
    //console.log("prod:", env); 
}else{
    dotenv.config({path: path.resolve("./.env")});
    //console.log("dev:", path.resolve("./.env"), env);
}

export const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  env.DATABASE_NAME,
  env.DATABASE_USER,
  env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: +env.DATABASE_PORT,
    dialect: "postgres",
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      idle: 30000,
      acquire: 60000,
    },
    define: {
      freezeTableName: true, 
    },
  }
);
/* If I commented out this Order define below, then the later syncDb method which called from the app.ts doesn't work */
/*
export const Order = sequelize.define("order", {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    // allowNull defaults to true
  },
});*/ 

/* this method will be called from the app.ts */
export const syncDb = async () => {
  try{
    await sequelize.sync();
    return true;
  }catch(err){
    throw err;
  }
};
```

From the app.ts file:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import path from "path";

import { syncDb } from "./util/database";

const app = express();

syncDb()
  .then((res) => {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Server started successfully.");
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Database sync() error: ", err); 
  });
```

And below is the order.ts file:

```
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../util/database";

const Order = sequelize.define("order", {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    // allowNull defaults to true
  },
}); 

export default Order;
```

Is that mean I have to put all the models definations into the same file? Or I made something wrong?

Comment: Try not to import the module with `sequelize` and modules with models into each other (cross-reference). Extract the logic of sync into another module where you can import sequelize instance and then all models

Comment: Thanks Anatoly, now I changed the order.ts file, and didn't run sequelize.define there, but just export the model define options there, and then use sequelize.define to define all models within database.ts file. And then all works fine.